# 3 way many-to-many typeOrm

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, relationship, nestjs, typeorm

Is there a way to implement 3 way many-to-many relationship in typeOrm

an example of a 3 way many-to-many relationship would be like

[3 way many-to-many relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryaNv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for that; it is actually written in typorm's documentation 
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md#many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties

many-to-many relations with custom properties
In case you need to have additional properties to your many-to-many relationship you have to create a new entity yourself. For example if you would like entities Post and Category to have a many-to-many relationship with additional order column, you need to create entity PostToCategory with two ManyToOne relations pointing in both directions and custom columns in it:

```
import { Entity, Column, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Post } from "./post";
import { Category } from "./category";

@Entity()
export class PostToCategory {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
public postToCategoryId!: number;

@Column()
public postId!: number;

@Column()
public categoryId!: number;

@Column()
public order!: number;

@ManyToOne(type => Post, post => post.postToCategories)
public post!: Post;

@ManyToOne(type => Category, category => category.postToCategories)
public category!: Category;
}
```

Additionally you will have to add a relationship like the following to Post and Category:

```
// category.ts
...
@OneToMany(type => PostToCategory, postToCategory => postToCategory.category)
public postToCategories!: PostToCategory[];

// post.ts
...
@OneToMany(type => PostToCategory, postToCategory => postToCategory.post)
public postToCategories!: PostToCategory[];
```

Comment: This isn't a 3 way many to many, its a two way with custom properties.

Comment: You’re right, it’s not, but it’s the only solution for a 3 way many to many relationship

Comment: but how does this provide a 3 way? I'm only seeing 2 entities referenced here. If you have some code that shows this working please post it if you can.

Comment: @rt_ By 3-way i think he means 3 tables, not 3 directions.  There are 3 entities total right, Post, Category, and PostToCategory